# Comparing 2 records in 2 BigQuery tables, is there a way to tell if they are the same or not?

Tags: google-bigquery

If we are comparing 2 records (lets say a customer record from yesterday and today), is there a way to tell if there has been at least one change (one value for one of the attributes has been changed) without having to compare values for each attribute?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you have to compare each column explicitly.

Note that `HASH()` can be helpful when doing bulk comparisons, but you still have to compare field by field to get the final answer.